# Google Apps Script: Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I wrote the following Google Apps Script function and set-up a daily project trigger to remove empty Gmail labels:

```
function removeEmptyGmailLabels() {
  // retrieve all labels
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    // loop over excluded labels and skip them
    for (var j = 0; j < excluded.length; j++) {
      if (labels[i].getName() != excluded[j]) {
        // Utilities.sleep(1000) 
        // retrieve all threads per label
        var threads = labels[i].getThreads();
        // determine if label contains no threads
        if (threads == "") {
          // delete empty label
          labels[i].deleteLabel();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This function produces the following error:

[image]

As you can see from the code above, I tried to add `Utilities.sleep(1000)` but commented it out again because it did not resolve the error.

How do I use `Utilities.sleep(1000)` appropriately?

Comment: Have you tried to increase sleep to 2000 or 5000?

Answer (score 1):

[Utilities.sleep(1000)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)) didn't help you much because the time being passed is in milliseconds. So you're just putting your function to sleep for 1 second. And depending on the length of `labels`, `excluded` and the number of threads each label is related to, it depends on how many times you're invoking the service.

I would also try the placing the statement to test out it's effects in different positions in the code. Especially try putting it after the 'labels[i].getThreads()' statement. It would put a second between fetching the threads and deleting the label if empty.

On closer look at the code, your function doesn't seem to be too efficient. Since `if (labels[i].getName() != excluded[j])` runs through the rest of the code for all the values of `excluded` that do not match `labels[i]`. Hence, if there were 10 values in `excluded` the code included in the for loop would still run for the other 9 values that `labels[i]` doesn't  match against. Hence, your "excluded" label would still end up being deleted. I would rather try something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
 var flag = true;
 for (var j = 0; j < excluded.length; j++) {
   if (labels[i].getName() == excluded[j]) {
     flag = false;
    }
  }
 if (flag == true) //Deletes only if there is no match in exceptions
 {
  //Checks only to see whether its empty
  if (labels[i].getThreads() == "") { 
    labels[i].deleteLabel();
   }
  }
 }
```

Try doing it this way and see if brings down your number. I don't think you should need `Utilities.sleep(1000)` now.